# Prevent scrolling on a smart phone for a specific screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, scroll

I simply need to prevent scrolling on a mobile device using JS and/or JQuery when a certain event occurs. I have a figure, when the user opens the figure the scrolling will be disabled, once it is closed, the scrolling will be enabled again. Target devices are:

- any IPhone from 4s up to the latest one (5 + 6 included)

Here are some of the things that I've tried but didn't work out:

**Method1 :**

```
                    document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchstart);
                    document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchmove);

                    function touchstart(e) {
                        e.preventDefault()
                    }

                    function touchmove(e) {
                        e.preventDefault()
                    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `position: fixed;` to `.no-scroll` which is applied to `html` and `body` when the figure is diplayed.

Added to JS to disable scrolling on open figure:

```
$('html, body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
```

Added to JS to enable scrolling on close figure:

```
$('html, body').removeClass('no-scroll');
```

CSS:

```
.no-scroll {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Hopefully this will help others with similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply disable document scroll with css:

```
$('body').addClass('overflow'); // use to disable scroll
//-
$('body').removeClass('overflow'); // use to enable scroll
```

And css: (or use jQuery [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/))

```
<style>
    .overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work on the devices, it works fine on the laptop tho such as the methods that I've mentioned above. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I using sth like that:

```
$.fn.isolatedScroll = ->
    @on 'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', (e) ->
      delta = e.wheelDelta or e.originalEvent and e.originalEvent.wheelDelta or -e.detail
      bottomOverflow = @scrollTop + $(@).outerHeight() - (@scrollHeight) >= 0
      topOverflow = @scrollTop <= 0
      if delta < 0 and bottomOverflow or delta > 0 and topOverflow then e.preventDefault()
```

And I use it ie. `$(@).find('ul').isolatedScroll()`